# How to generate dynamic authorization code using JWT api, user and password

Tags: php, api, jwt, authorization, token

Right now i am able to get the data from api by using below code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://test-api.test.org/user/token",
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoN2ZiQwiZXhwIjoxNTk0MjY5NjI"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

$data = json_decode($response, true);

echo $response;
```

But authorization code is expiring every 15 min and i have to refresh the token after that interval in php.

My requirement is:

1. To generate token dynamically by using jwt api, user and password
2. check for if the token is valid or expired after sometime
3. once the token is expired then refresh it and generate a new token dynamically.

Thanks in advance for all your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of my problem and its working perfectly fine.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://{instance}/app/oauth/token",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"username\":\"yourusername\", \"yourpassword\":\"{pass}\"}",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"cache-control: no-cache",
"content-type: application/json"
),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
echo $response;
}
```